# Oracle - "bad bind variable" with bind variable inside function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle19c, bind-variables

Why does this code:

```sql
with
function qry(v in varchar2) return varchar2 is
   begin
      return owa_util.ite(v like ('%' || lower(:param) || '%'),'Y','N');
   end;
select * from my_table where qry(my_col) = 'Y'
```

Gives me the following error:

```
ORA-06553: PLS-49: bad bind variable 'PARAM'
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 46
```

Comment: you can't stick a bind variable like that inside a function.  pass it is as a parameter like the way you do for "v"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have declared the `param` bind variable; if you haven't then that is your first problem.

You do not need a function:

```sql
select *
from   my_table
where  my_col LIKE '%' || LOWER( :param ) || '%'
```

If you really want a function *(don't as it would prevent you using an index on the column)* then pass the bind value as an argument:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION qry(
    value  IN VARCHAR2,
    filter IN VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN v LIKE '%' || lower(filter) || '%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
  END;
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  qry(my_col, :param) = 'Y'
```